# How to make a MO Diagram for F_2^+2 in LaTeX

Tags: modiagram

I am trying to make the MO Diagram for F_2^+2 in LaTeX and I can't figure out how to get the p sigma orbital to be higher than the two p pi orbitals. The LaTeX stuff below is what I have right now and I have attached a picture of what I want. Does anyone know how to edit the MO Diagram to get this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{modiagram}
\usepackage{mhchem}


\title{mo diagram}
\author{mary stuart}
\date{November 2021}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Using the molecular orbital diagram below, fill in the electrons for the ground electronic state of the F$_2^{+}$ molecule.  Determine its ground electronic state term symbol, including the spin multiplicity.
 \begin{center}
    

\begin{modiagram}[labels,names,style=plain]
 \atom[F]{left}{
   2p = {0;pair,pair,up}
 }
 \atom[F]{right}{
   2p = {0;pair,up,up}
  }
 \molecule[$F_2^+$]{
   2pMO  = {1.8,.4;pair,pair,pair,pair,up} ,
   color = {2piy* = black}
 }
\end{modiagram}

 \begin{modiagram}[labels]
\atom [F]{left} {2s = {;pair}}
\atom [F]{right}{2s = {;pair}}
 \molecule [\ce{$F_2$}]{
    2sMO ={.75;pair},
    label = {2sigma = 2p$\sigma$}}

    
\end{modiagram}
 \end{center}   

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Any advice would be really helpful!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
\begin{modiagram}[labels,names,style=plain]
                \atom[]{left}{
                    2p = {0;,,}
                }
                \atom[]{right}{
                    2p = {0;,,}
                }
                \molecule[]{
                    2pMO = {1.2/2,2/1;,,},
                    color = {2piy* = black}
                }
            \end{modiagram}
            
            \begin{modiagram}[labels,names]
                \atom [F]{left} {2s=0 }
                \atom [F]{right}{2s=0 }
                \molecule [\ce{$F_2$}]{
                    2sMO ={.75},
                    label = {2sigma = 2p$\sigma$}}
                
                
            \end{modiagram}
```

[image]

OR THIS:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{modiagram,chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
    \MOsetup{
        style=square, 
        labels,
        names,
        AO-width=8pt,
        labels-fs=\footnotesize,
        labels-style={blue}
    }
    %============================== F2 ======================
    \begin{MOdiagram}
        \atom[\ce{F}]{left}{
            1s  = {;}, 
            2s  = {;}, 
            2p = {;}
        }
        \atom[\ce{F}]{right}{
            1s  = {;}, 
            2s  = {;}, 
            2p = {;}
        }
        \molecule[\ce{F2}]{
            1sMO = {;,}, 
            2sMO = {;,}, 
            2pMO = {0.9/2,1.7/1;,,},
            color = { 1sigma*=red, 2sigma*=red }
        }   
    \end{MOdiagram}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect!!! Thank you so much :)